# JQuery while loop and setTime out function lead to stuck the browser

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to automate a slider by using following Jquery code

```
while(true){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.bx-next').click();
    }, 3000);
}
```

but this leads to crash the browser..
Any better way???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an endless loop every 3000 ms, use `setInterval` not `setTimeout` and get rid of the `while(true)`:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.bx-next').click();
}, 3000);
```

**Docs**: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp